# How to choose range with php If condition

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a some auto-generation string with number. It's can be from 0 to 99.
How i can choose each ***"2,3,4"*** from this? ***(x2,x3,x4 etc)***

```
$n = 53;

if($i == ?){ echo "there is 3";}
```

What i need to print instead "?" symbol?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What do you mean by "choose each "2,3,4" from this"?

Comment: @BrendanLong I need choose every third one (also 2 and 4).. x2, x3, x4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

really just guessing here:

```
<?php

$i=23;//13,33,43,9999999993
if(substr($i,-1) == 3){ 
echo "there is 3";
}
```

the code

```
substr($i,-1)
```

returns the last character of the string $i

---

to cover 2 or 3 or 4

```
$i=24;
if(in_array(substr($i,-1),array(2,3,4))){ 
echo "ends in 2 or 3 or 4";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The algorithmic solution here would be:

```
if ($i % 10 == 3) {
```

`%` is the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php). Here dividing `53` by `10` for example, thus leaving `3` as result for the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is to tell if a string contains a character (like `53` contains a `3`), you can use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) or [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) (there are probably several other functions that do this too):

```
$i = "53";
if(strpos($i, "3") !== FALSE) {
    echo "There is a 3 in $i";
}
```